# Can you hide the value colum in vb.net listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am coming from MS Access VBA where I use listboxes to provide a clickable list of items returning a value for the clicked item.  The user does not have to see the value column, just the item description. In that environment you can control the width of each column, setting the value column to zero width, so it is hidden.

Moving to VB.net it does not seem possible to vary column width or hide the value column.

Is that correct?  Is there an alternative control to provide this feature?

thx

It does not seem possible ot set columnwiths independantly of each other.

Comment: The difference between MSAccess and vb.net development is you've got a whole heap more scope and choice with controls, particularly when it comes to multi column data structures.  What you might be familiar with can now be done (arguably) better with different controls.  The other thing to really look at before getting to committed is data binding practices

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Objects and classes in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/),  [Walkthrough: Defining Classes (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/walkthrough-defining-classes)

Comment: [ComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), [DropDownStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), [DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.datasource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: [DisplayMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), [ValueMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: Not only can you hide the value column, you can't even show it in the first place. Assuming you're talking about Windows Forms, a `ListBox` doesn't have multiple columns. For that you'd use a `DataGridView`. A `ListBox` will only display a single list of values. As already indicated, you would create a list with columns/properties for the text to display and the corresponding value and you would then bind that to the `ListBox`. If the data is coming from a database, that list might be a `DataTable`.

Comment: See my post below. You can MOST certainly include many and multiple columns in the combo data source (but, you only get to display one column). However, since you were asking how to "hide" those extra columns - see my post below - I show how this works, since combo box DOES support multiple hidden column values - it just don't support display of the multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is sort-of yes.

In .net, the combo box (dropdown list) or listbox has the ability to have display on 1 column (but does support having multiple columns in the data source - see my Edit part as to how this works).

So, the combo/listbox has the all-important ability to have/enjoy/use 2 columns (a classic hidden PK value, and then a display value).

In other words you do not have to hide the column, and out of the box, the .net controls have this feature. So, you don't have to "size" to 0 like in Access, but the feature is built in.

Let's do a simple example.

I have a combo box, want to select a hotel name.

Now, of course we would not display or require the user to type in or select a PK row id of the hotel name, but of course would display the user and display the hotel names.

But, like any database system, upon selection of the Hotel name, we want the underlying pk id.

So, say this combo box on a form in vb.net:

[image]

So, "display" member is the "display" column from the data source. (so, that would be the un-hidden column in ms-access combo).

And then we want to set the PK id (the hidden value - like those combo in MS Access).

Thus this:

[image]

So, in .net you don't "hide" some column, which to be fair is a bit of a kluge in MS Access.

So, you have the correct settings here - TWO columns, the display one (Display Member), and then the hidden column "value" (Value Member).

So, let's write some code to fill out the combo, and then show those 2 selected values.

So, on form load, then this to load combo:

```
Private Sub HotelCombo_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ComboBox1.DataSource =
        MyRst("SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")

End Sub
```

And our selected index event for the combo is this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then

        Debug.Print($"Combo selected index = {ComboBox1.SelectedIndex}")
        Debug.Print($"Hotel hidden value = {ComboBox1.SelectedValue}")
        Debug.Print($"Hotel text (display) value = {ComboBox1.Text}")

    End If

End Sub
```

Output (immediate window)

```
Combo selected index = 0
Hotel hidden value = 78
Hotel text (display) value = Athabasca Hotel
```

So, in above we get:

- The "index" of the choice.
- The hidden value (data base PK value in this example).
- The text the user selected.

So, yes, the listbox/combo box in .net has the 2 columns that one would typical need in NEAR ALL cases.

I don't like having to type code to get a data table over and over, so I used this:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

Note that the combo or listbox is not multi-column "display", but thankfully, the 99% of cases in which you need a PK database id, but display of some "friendly" text is available for the combo or listbox.

### Edit

What about having + using extra columns when select? While you can't display more then one column in the combo box, you can have from other columns.

Now, I suppose one could re-pull the database row based on the above approach in which two columns are available.

However, you are not limited to having just 2 columns (hidden PK and display value). So, you just don't have multiple-column display ability like we have in Access (well, in .net we have the 2 columns (hidden + display).

But, let's change our code, and say when you select the combo box, I need city, and description, and is if active.

So, we drop in city text box, description, and Active.

Our form now has this:

[image]

And our 2 code stubs are now this:

```
Private Sub HotelCombo_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT ID, HotelName, City, Description, Active
        FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

    ComboBox1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1

End Sub
```

So note in above, we did include as many columns as we want to have.

Now, in the combo box event, we have this code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then

        Debug.Print($"Combo selected index = {ComboBox1.SelectedIndex}")
        Debug.Print($"Hotel hidden value = {ComboBox1.SelectedValue}")
        Debug.Print($"Hotel text (display) value = {ComboBox1.Text}")

        ' get hidden columns (extra columns not display)

        Dim rRowData As DataRowView = ComboBox1.SelectedItem

        txtCity.Text = rRowData("City")
        ckActive.Checked = rRowData("Active")
        txtDescription.Text = rRowData("Description")


    End If

End Sub
```

Note how we can use the extra hidden columns.

So, while we don't have the ability to display the extra columns like in MS Access (but only one display), we can include + have additional columns - they are in fact hidden by default.

So, note the code use of selected item. That item is persisted when you load/fill the combo box. And you can thus pull out and use the hidden columns, and do so without having to re-pull, or "dlookup()" the extra columns you need upon selection.

So, in some ways, this setup is better then access for the extra hidden columns (you don't have to muck around with trying to match up a column width value of "0" in some messy ";" delimited string).

However, we do lose the ability to display more then one column here, but vb.net listbox/combo box does have the ability to let you store and use multiple hidden columns, as above shows.